# Limit image height with div

Tags: image, html

do you know the way to limit image in the div ? I'm creating a website like a http://bezuzyteczna.pl/ On this site if your image has mor than 200px height it is limitig to 100px and on the bottom is showig "Show More" Have anyone any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a max-height and overflow to hidden on the wrapping container of the image.

```
<div class="image"><img src="[path/to/images]" alt="" /></div>

.image {
  max-height:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
}
.image > img {
  display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qx7Ps/1/